# php file with both internal and external reference

Tags: php, html

I have situation in which I have 2 php files. The first say php1 calls php2. Now php2 is contained in the action attribute of the form1 in php1 therefore it can reference all the tags of form1 by their names via $_POST[]. But php2 contains code that should also manipulate data contained in the tags of php2. Every time I try to access a tag of php2 via $_POST[] it says "undifined index". How can I solve the problem so that php2 can also access its inner tags via $_POST?

php1

```
<form id="ee" method="POST" onsubmit="return validatelogin();"  action="login.php">

<div id="container" style="text-align: center;">

<div id="header" class="class_header">
<a href="project_index.php" align="right" color="white">Go back to index</a>
</div>
<div id="body" >
<br/><br/>
<font color="white" ><h1 color="white" style="font-size:200%;" align="center">Log In</h1></font>    
</div>
<div id="body" style="height: 30%; width: 60%;" class="div">

</br></br>

<fieldset id="login"><legend><strong>Log In</strong></legend>
<table>
<tr>
<th>Username</th>
<td><input type="text" name="username"></td>
</tr>   
<tr>
<th>Password</th>
<td><input type="password" name="password"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th><input type="button" value="Forgot Password" name="forgotpassword" class="link" onClick="forgotpassword1();"/></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td>
<input type="button" name="Log In" value="Log In" onClick="login1();" >
</td>
</tr>   
</table>
```

php2

```
<?php

$username=$_POST["username"];
$password=$_POST["password"]; 
$password=md5($password);
$conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","askthedoctor");
$sql="select password from login where username='".$username."';";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);

if($row[0]!=$password)
{ 
  echo "The username or password that you entered are incorrect!";
  echo "<br/>";
  echo "<a href=\"project_login.php\">Go back to login</a>";
  die();
}

$sql1="select userprivileges from login where username='".$username."';";
$sql2="select image_path from registration1 where id=(select id from login      where username='".$username."');";
$result1=mysqli_query($conn,$sql1);
$result2=mysqli_query($conn,$sql2); 
$row1=mysqli_fetch_array($result1);
$row2=mysqli_fetch_array($result2);
$imagepath=$row2[0];
if($row1[0]==2)
{
?>

<form  id="patient" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"     action="login.php" >

<div id="container">

<div id="header" class="class_header">
<a href="project_login.php" align="right" color="white">Sign Out</a>
</div>

<div id="body" >
<br/>
<table class="table">
<tr>
<td><font color="white" ><h1 color="white" style="font-size:200%;"    align="center">Welcome <?php echo $username;?></h1></font></td>   
<td> <div id="box"><image height="65px" width="65px" src="<?php echo   $imagepath; ?>"></div></td>
<tr>    
</table>
</div>



<div id="separator" ></div>
<div id="separator" ></div>

<div id="bodyy" style="height: 60%; width: 60%;"  class="div">

<br/><br/><br/>

<fieldset id="registration">
<table class="table">

<tr>
<th>Messages</th>
<?php

$sql="select title from messages where paitient_id=(select id from login where username='".$username."');";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
?>  
<th>Problem Description</th>
<th>Doctor's Answer</th>
<th></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><select name="title"> 
<?php echo "<option value=\"mesazhi1\">".$row[0]."</option>";}?>
</select>
</td>
<?php
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$title=$_POST['title'];///////Here happens the problem**********
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$sql1="select patient_text from messages where title='".$title."';";
$sql2="select doctor_text from messages where title='".$title."';";
$result1=mysqli_query($conn,$sql1);
$result2=mysqli_query($conn,$sql2);
$row1=mysqli_fetch_array($result1);
$row2=mysqli_fetch_array($result2);
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
function displaymessage()
{

    var doctoranswer=<?php echo $row1[0];?>;
    var patientquestion=<?php echo $row2[0];?>;
    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML=doctoranswer;
    document.getElementById("question").innerHTML=patientquestion;

}
</script>
<td><textarea rows="4" col="50" id ="question" readonly> </textarea></td>
<td><textarea rows="4" col="50" id ="answer" readonly> </textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="button" name="openmessage" value="Display Selected Message" onClick="displaymessage()"></td>
<td><input type="button" name="btnSubmit" value="Ask a new question" ></td>
</tr>

</table>
</fieldset>
</div>

</div>


</form>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Care to include the code for `php1` and `php2`?

Comment: Please post your html code and an example of the code of php1 and php2.

Comment: I don't suppose you have the full error also, it should specify what `undifined index` is and where it is.

Comment: I am very sorry for the redundancy...I have commented the line where the problem happens

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that you haven't an input field in your php1 with the name "title". For achieving this you can add

```
 <input type="hidden" name="title" value="yourTitle" />
```

You can also test if the index exists, so that php doesn't exit the code.

```
 if(isset($_POST["title"])) {
    $title = $_POST["title"];
    // ....
 } else {
    // no index is setup
    //...
 }
```

Comment: But i already have a tag named "title" it is this one: 
      <td><select name="title"> 
      <?php echo "<option value=\"mesazhi1\">".$row[0]."</option>";}?>
       </select>
       </td>

Comment: I see, but this creates the index $_POST["title"] AFTER submitting the form. When you call the form without performing the post, there is no index. So I think it would be the best, if you check whether this index exists like in my answer.